# Redireccion en ajax no funciona

Tags: ajax, laravel, vistas

Tengo una funcion que guarda calificaciones:

```
<script>
function guardarNotas(){
    var object = [];

    $(".nota").each(function (index, element){
        object.push({
            'idMatricula': $(element).data('idMatricula'),
            'idEvaluacion': $(element).data('idEvaluacion'),
            'nota': $(element).val()
        });
    });

    $.ajax('../savecalificacionesasignatura', {
        contentType: 'aplication/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(object),
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('[name="_token"]').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('se ha guardado');

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data)
        }
    });

}
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
public function guardarNotas(Request $request)
{
    $notas = $request->input();

    foreach ($notas as $nota){
        $nota = Nota::updateOrCreate([
            'id_matricula' => $nota['idMatricula'],
            'id_evaluacion' => $nota['idEvaluacion']
            ], ['nota' => $nota['nota']]);
    }
    //responder true or false ? segun se guarda o devolver error
    return response()->json(array('success' => true));

}
```

Quiero que al momento de apretar el botón guardar me redireccione a otra vista, ya he intentado en el success con:

```
window.location='thank-you.html'
```

`window.location.href='thank-you.html'`

```
location.href="page.html"
```

pero no logro la redireccion. Tambien probe en el controlador con, return redirect::to(""), return view(""), return url(""). ALguien sabe realizar correctamente la redireccion

Comment: En la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects)  de laravel especifica como redireccionar

Answer (score 1):

Para la dirección intenta esto:

```
    window.location = "@Url.Action("EditarFactura", "Facturas")";
```

si lo pones en un método quedaría algo así por ejemplo:

```
function Edit(Id)
{
   localStorage.setItem("FacId", JSON.stringify(Id));
   window.location = "@Url.Action("EditarFactura", "Facturas")";
}
```